# Are art styles subject to IP protection?

Tags: intellectual-property

Is the art style of a comic, film, video game, etc. protectable by IP (copyright, trade dress, trademark, etc.)?

Comment: I think the question could be rephrased to answer itself: Could the first person to make "street art" have sued Basquiat for copyright infringement? Was the first arthouse film director entitled to the profits from Citizen Kane and Requiem For A Dream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copyright

Style in art is a *particular method of expression*. Copyright does **only** cover the expression itself. That means it most notably does not cover [Ideas, methods, systems, names, titles, short phrases, typeface, fonts, lettering, blank forms, familiar symbols, and designs](https://www.copyright.gov/circs/circ33.pdf). A style is a method of expressinjg, which is expressly not copyrightable.

### Patent

To be patentable, [you need to show that it is a](https://www.uspto.gov/patents/basics/essentials#questions)

> new and useful process, machine, manufacture, or composition of matter, or any new and useful improvement thereof.
>
> new, original, and ornamental design for an article of manufacture
>
> distinct and new variety of plant, including cultivated sports, mutants, hybrids, and newly found seedlings, other than a tuber-propagated plant or a plant found in an uncultivated state,

> So, for a patent to be issued, your invention must meet four conditions:
>
> 1. Able to be used (the invention must work and cannot just be a theory)
> 2. A clear description of how to make and use the invention
> 3. New, or “novel” (something not done before)
> 4. “Not obvious,” as related to a change to something already invented

As such, the only thing that *could* be patentable is a **novel tool or method to create** for most art is unavaileable.